# Get a div value from an iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, cross-domain, reverse-proxy

I have two pages, one runs in an iframe in the other page: test.php runs in check.php. Test.php is to function as a proxy in order to circumvent cross-origin. The iframe works and gives the right values. But when i try to take a value from a div id in the parent page, I get this response: 
Uncaught SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin "http://localhost" from accessing a frame with origin "http://www.allow-any-origin.appspot.com". Protocols, domains, and ports must match.

Here is the code I have:

check.php

```
    <iframe id="vd" src="http://localhost/vd/test.php/test.php" width="720"       
    height="300" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" allowtransparency="true">
    </iframe>
    <form>
    <input id="test" type="button" value="Submit">
    </form>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery('#test').click(function() { 
    var mb = 
    document.getElementById('vd').contentWindow.document.getElementById
    ('#saldo_result'); 
    });        
    </script>
```

test.php

```
    <form action="http://www.allow-any-
    origin.appspot.com/http://vend.giftcardservices.nl/saldo/check?
    show_form=0&card_id=3005&card_id=&ajax=1" method="GET">
    <input type="text" name="card_id" value="3005">
    <input type="text" name="card_id" value="">
    <br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
```

I assumed this path was to have the browser accept this way. Can anybody see where I am going wrong?

Comment: If that site is setting CORS, use Ajax. If not create a proxy on your domain to fetch it.

Comment: That's what I figured I did in this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did something like this posting from php.

client <-> yourPostScript.php <-> external web page.

Form post data to yourPostScript.php that posts to external allow-any-origin.appspot.com you get the response in yourPostScript.php and you echo it.

Sorry, i hope this is not ilegal..

--Edit--

test.php code:

```
<form action="yourPostScript.php" method="GET">
<input type="text" name="card_id" value="3005">
<input type="text" name="card_id" value="">
<br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
```

yourPostScript.php code: (just a snippet that should work for demostration)

```
   <?php 
/* validating method and fields i think is enough for ignoring images and others..*/
   if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']!='POST') die;
   if(!$_POST['card_id']) die;

    $url = 'http://vend.giftcardservices.nl/saldo/check?
    show_form=0&card_id=3005&card_id=&ajax=1';
    $data = array('card_id' => $_POST['card_id'], 'other_field' => $_POST['other_field']);

// use key 'http' even if you send the request to https://...
$options = array(
    'http' => array(
        'header'  => "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n",
        'method'  => 'POST',
        'content' => http_build_query($data),
    ),
);
$context  = stream_context_create($options);
echo $result = file_get_contents($url, false, $context); ?>
```

Comment: This way the post response is still your website and you can access to it.

Comment: You can post to any website you want .. It's not illegal unless used for malicious intent.  If the site owners didn't want it to happen, they'd look at the headers and lock it down on the server side.  And, for that matter, many API's work this way, generating content from a POST or GET request cross domain.

Comment: Is that not what I did by using the test.php in between? Or am I misunderstanding you?

Comment: Thanks for the response! On my test this gives just a white page.

Comment: I've tweaked your code a little bit and it worked. Thank you so much!

Comment: Cool! Can you suggest me the code so i can correct it on the answer if someone else need it?

Comment: I've added it underneath yours. Perhaps it's not the best way to do this but it works.

Comment: if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']!='GET') die;
$data = array('card_id' => $_GET['card_id'], 'card_id' => $_GET['card_id']);
// use key 'http' even if you send the request to https://...
$options = array(
'http' => array(
'header'  => "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n",
'method'  => 'GET',
'content' => http_build_query($data),
),
);
$card_id = $_GET['card_id'];
$context  = stream_context_create($options);
$result = file_get_contents(sprintf("http://vend.giftcardservices.nl/saldo/check?show_form=0&card_id=3005&card_id=$card_id&ajax=1" , false, $context));

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript will not reach into frames ...  The standards for JS are set pretty high that way.  That way I don't just serve someone else's page as an iFrame and use my JavaScript to collect login details etc etc etc ..

Comment: Well, its just to take one numerical output value and be able to calculate with it. No bad intentions to be sure.

Comment: Bad intentions or not .. If it were "allowed" it'd be a security hole that anyone could exploit.  Your intentions aren't in question.  It's an impossibility on purpose, for security reasons.

Comment: Sorry to say, no :-(

Comment: Not with JS anyway  ..  You'll have to do this server-side if you want it done ..

Comment: Bummer. Thanks for the quick responses!